# SetMsiAssemblyNameFileVersion breaks the Strong Name of assemblies

Tags: wix

I use the “SetMsiAssemblyNameFileVersion” property in our MergeModules.

So I get a zero at the end of the assembly version.

This breaks the strong name for the assemblies.

In the result Visual Studio setup projects can no longer recognized the assemblies as dependencies.

The automatic adding of MSM’s is broken.

Is there a way to get around this?

regards

Kai

From Binder.cs  Version 3.6

// there is a bug in fusion that requires the assembly's "version" attribute

// to be equal to or longer than the "fileVersion" in length when its present;

// the workaround is to prepend zeroes to the last version number in the assembly version

Answer (score 0):

File a bug against Fusion to fix the root issue **or** file a bug against the Visual Studio Setup Projects to use the same work around so that packages with the fileVersion set will install correctly.